# Why doesn't mb_substr and mb_strlen work as expected in this case?

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove the first and last chars of a string. I'm experiencing weirdness.

Check it out:

```
$string = 'This is a test.';
$string = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string) - 1);
var_dump($string);
```

Output:

```
string(14) "his is a test."
```

And then this:

```
$string = 'This is a test.';
$string = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string) - 2);
var_dump($string);
```

Output:

```
string(13) "his is a test"
```

The length of the string minus 1 should be enough, but I have to go TWO minus. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your string `This is a test.` length is **15**.

To get new string without last and first symbols - you need **13** symbols, which is exactly `mb_strlen($string) - 2`.

Also, [third argument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php#refsect1-function.mb-substr-parameters) of `mb_substr` is **not position** of last considered symbol, it is **length** of the substring that you want to receive.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand this answer. It's as if you meant to continue writing the explanation, but hit "Add Comment" too quickly?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? Your string without 2 symbols will have length __13__. Next you get 13 symbols from 1 position which gives you what you need.

Comment: I thought I described my confusion in my question. Why does not the length of the string minus 1 char remove the last char? What am I missing?

Comment: Because you start from the char in position 1, which is the __second__ char.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah. I think I must have managed to misread the manual. It does say it's the length. I guess it makes senese.